# How to show only result but disappear button in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component, react-state

I am facing a few issues. I will be glad and thankful if someone help.

1. In the first one, when I click on the button to show options array which I get through props from the parent component. It shows options.map is not a function. But, in concole.log() this.state.options get filled with props through button click. What I need is button is shown but when I click it disappears and the only list of the array is shown.

   ```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class DoctorSelectTiming extends Component {
      state = {
        options: [],
        isLoading: false
      } 

      selectTiming = (props) => {
        const setItems = this.state.options.push(...this.props.props);
        this.setState({options: setItems, isLoading: true});
        console.log(this.state.options );
      }

      render() {
        const {isLoading, options } = this.state;
        return (
          <div>
          {!isLoading ? <button onClick={this.selectTiming}>Select Timing</button> : (options.map(option => <li>{option}</li>))
          }
          </div>
              )
      }
    }

    export default DoctorSelectTiming;
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead in your `selectTiming` function:

```
selectTiming = () => {
   // set the loading to true first and setting it to false afterwards.
   this.setState({ isLoading: true });
   const newItems = [...this.props.props];
   this.setState({ options: newItems, isLoading: false });
}
```

You are assigning `this.state.options.push(...this.props.props)`, which in theory, returns ONLY the length of the array after the element was pushed in the array.

This is an example code of what you did:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4]
console.log(arr) // [1,2,3,4]
const anotherArr = []
const newArr = anotherArr.push(arr) // assigning it to newArr will only return the length 
                                    // of the array after it was pushed.
console.log(newArr) // 4
```

So, the better approach would be assigning setItems with the actual value of `this.props.props` instead of directly modifying the actual state, which is a BAD practice. Also, the argument `props` is unnecessary since props is already available locally in your component.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I do this "options: [...this.props.props];" directly inside state. Its working smoothly without any error in console.

Comment: Yes you can! I think that's better and less code! :)

Comment: If you find my answer you can mark my answer as best answer so anyone with related issue would see this! Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62849796/how-to-create-an-array-outside-class-component-or-reference-state-sibling-to-nex