# How to create an array outside class component or reference state sibling to next sibling React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component, react-state

I need a solution for radio buttons, but the options array which is the main array is outside the class component. In this case, I will get OPTIONS array items through props but not hardcoded. How is it possible for me to

1. Pass props outside class component
2. Make OPTIONS state object and then pass it to checkboxes, which is inside state.

   ```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import Checkbox from "./Checkbox";

    const OPTIONS = ["One", "Two", "Three"];

    class App extends Component {
      state = {
        checkboxes: OPTIONS.reduce(
          (options, option) => ({
            ...options,
            [option]: false
          }),
          {}
        )
      };

      selectAllCheckboxes = isSelected => {
        Object.keys(this.state.checkboxes).forEach(checkbox => {
          // BONUS: Can you explain why we pass updater function to setState instead of an object?
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            checkboxes: {
              ...prevState.checkboxes,
              [checkbox]: isSelected
            }
          }));
        });
      };

      selectAll = () => this.selectAllCheckboxes(true);

      deselectAll = () => this.selectAllCheckboxes(false);

      handleCheckboxChange = changeEvent => {
        const { name } = changeEvent.target;

        this.setState(prevState => ({
          checkboxes: {
            ...prevState.checkboxes,
            [name]: !prevState.checkboxes[name]
          }
        }));
      };

      handleFormSubmit = formSubmitEvent => {
        formSubmitEvent.preventDefault();

        Object.keys(this.state.checkboxes)
          .filter(checkbox => this.state.checkboxes[checkbox])
          .forEach(checkbox => {
            console.log(checkbox, "is selected.");
          });
      };

      createCheckbox = option => (
        <Checkbox
          label={option}
          isSelected={this.state.checkboxes[option]}
          onCheckboxChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
          key={option}
        />
      );

      createCheckboxes = () => OPTIONS.map(this.createCheckbox);

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row mt-5">
              <div className="col-sm-12">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                  {this.createCheckboxes()}

                  <div className="form-group mt-2">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2"
                      onClick={this.selectAll}
                    >
                      Select All
                    </button>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2"
                      onClick={this.deselectAll}
                    >
                      Deselect All
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                      Save
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke options directly in state and then use constructor to map them to checkboxes. hope this helps.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
 import Checkbox from "./Checkbox";

 class App extends Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props)
     this.state.checkboxes = this.state.options.reduce(
       (options, option) => ({
         ...options,
         [option]: false
       }),
       {}
     )
   }
   state = {
     options: ["One", "Two", "Three"]
   };

   selectAllCheckboxes = isSelected => {
     Object.keys(this.state.checkboxes).forEach(checkbox => {
       // BONUS: Can you explain why we pass updater function to setState instead of an object?
       this.setState(prevState => ({
         checkboxes: {
           ...prevState.checkboxes,
           [checkbox]: isSelected
         }
       }));
     });
   };

   selectAll = () => this.selectAllCheckboxes(true);

   deselectAll = () => this.selectAllCheckboxes(false);

   handleCheckboxChange = changeEvent => {
     const { name } = changeEvent.target;

     this.setState(prevState => ({
       checkboxes: {
         ...prevState.checkboxes,
         [name]: !prevState.checkboxes[name]
       }
     }));
   };

   handleFormSubmit = formSubmitEvent => {
     formSubmitEvent.preventDefault();

     Object.keys(this.state.checkboxes)
       .filter(checkbox => this.state.checkboxes[checkbox])
       .forEach(checkbox => {
         console.log(checkbox, "is selected.");
       });
   };

   createCheckbox = option => (
     <Checkbox
       label={option}
       isSelected={this.state.checkboxes[option]}
       onCheckboxChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
       key={option}
     />
   );

   createCheckboxes = () => this.state.options.map(this.createCheckbox);

   render() {
     return (
       <div className="container">
         <div className="row mt-5">
           <div className="col-sm-12">
             <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
               {this.createCheckboxes()}

               <div className="form-group mt-2">
                 <button
                   type="button"
                   className="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2"
                   onClick={this.selectAll}
                 >
                   Select All
                 </button>
                 <button
                   type="button"
                   className="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2"
                   onClick={this.deselectAll}
                 >
                   Deselect All
                 </button>
                 <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                   Save
                 </button>
               </div>
             </form>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     );
   }
 }

 export default App;
```